# lyr replaceDataSource not reflecting

Tags: arcpy, layers

The changes I made to the MXD with ArcPy is not reflecting the changes in ArcMap.

```
arcpy.env.workspace= "C:\Users\UserID\Desktop"       
mxdlocation=os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace,mxdname)
mxdloc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdlocation)

fullPathToNewWorkspace =os.path.join(arcpy.env.workspace,gdb)
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxdloc):
  for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxdloc, '', df):
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
        dataName = os.path.basename(lyr.dataSource)
        #using the gdb found within the zip folder.
        lyr.replaceDataSource(fullPathToNewWorkspace, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", dataName, True)
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

**This is the output of the arcpy codes.**

[image: output of arcpy code]

The properties of the layer shows that it belongs to the old datasource

[image: This is the properties of the layer]

Comment: How is your `mxdloc` variable declared? You should save your mxd, if you're not running your script from ArcMap with the desired mxd open.

Comment: I am running the script from within ArcMap so I can see the results, edited the question so you can see the mxdloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your mxd is open, use

```
mxdloc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
```

Changes made to your mxd on your disk (by referencing the mxd's path) won't be visible if the mxd is open in ArcMap so depending on where you are running it you may need to add

```
mxdloc.save()
```

Comment: Ah thanks so if i run the script outside, then all i need to do is to save it?

Comment: Yes! add `mxdloc.save()`

Answer (score -2):

```
#In ArcGIS Python script windows (only shapefile): 
workspace_type = 'SHAPEFILE_WORKSPACE'

oldlyr = r'C:\TMP\OLD.shp'
newlyr = r'C:\TMP\NEW.shp'
workspace = r'C:\TMP\NEW.shp' #(!!!with shapefile name and extension!!!)
dataset_name = 'NEW' #(!!!without extension!!!)
oldlyr.replaceDataSource(workspace, workspace_type, dataset_name)
#In independence Python script (only shapefile):
oldlyr = r'C:\TMP\OLD.shp'
newlyr = r'C:\TMP\NEW.shp'
workspace = r'C:\TMP\' #(!!!without shapefile name and extension!!!)
dataset_name = 'NEW' (!!!without extension!!!)
oldlyr.replaceDataSource(workspace, workspace_type, dataset_name)
```

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Please do not post the same answer in multiple threads; and please explain your answer.  For information on how this site works, visit our [help].

Comment: It's difficult to determine whether you are attempting to answer or asking a new question (since it doesn't have any words, a "wall of code" post is likely to be down-voted because of this). This doesn't answer the question, though, so it is likely to be deleted.